# How to Find and Print using Shell Script in AIX Server?

Tags: aix

I have one big file with the content as below:

```
dn: CN=Brower\, Stephen,OU=Recipients,OU=Mailboxes,OU=Exchange2000,DC=raritanval,DC=edu
changetype: modify
replace: department
department: Computer Science
-

dn: CN=Brower\, Stephen,OU=Recipients,OU=Mailboxes,OU=Exchange2000,DC=raritanval,DC=edu
changetype: modify
replace: description
description: Computer Science
```

-

I want to create multiple file which will have the output starting from "dn:" to "-", it means it will start searching from dn: and will print till - in one file and so on. And there is a requirement to have some standard name for the file as well which will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An awk script can be helpful. Since you are running on AIX, you might want to get GNU awk (or gawk) installed. gawk has many more useful features than vanilla awk.

```
awk 'BEGIN{fnum=1;}($1=="dn:"){flag=1; x=""}(flag==1){x=x "\n" $0}($1=="-"){flag=0; fn="file" fnum; print x > fn; close (fn); fnum++;}'
```

This dumps the data into files that are sequentially numbered file1, file2, ...

[Edited to reflect OP's needs and added close(fn)]

Comment: I need sort of script using some simple way to execute the above stuff i mentioned. Help me to achieve that please.

Comment: But the file i have, last two comma separated names are same so in my case only one file generated as same as original using the above command. Let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Looking at the two records you provided, they have the same fields at the end. For instance, both records you list end in "DC=raritanval,DC=edu". However,  they do differ in the "replace:" field. Is this how all your records are structured? Will any two records that have the same ending field (e.g., "DC=raritanval,DC=edu") have different "replace:" fields?

Comment: dn: CN=Kletz\, Pattiann,OU=Recipients,OU=Mailboxes,OU=Exchange2000,DC=raritanval,DC=edu
changetype: modify
replace: title
title: Assistant Professor-Business
-

dn: CN=Krov\, Kathleen,OU=Recipients,OU=Mailboxes,OU=Exchange2000,DC=raritanval,DC=edu
changetype: modify
replace: department
department: Nursing
-             So i provided few more data for example, i want these 5 line starting from dn: upto - should written in some different file say file1 shud contain 5 line and file2 shud next contain 5 lines starting from dn: to - ignore the space. I hope i m clear to provide the detail.

Comment: So finally there will be many files generated, file name could be anything, file1,file2 like that. And each file will contain 5 lines as i mentioned earlier. So liek if found dn: it shud write upto - in different file. And then again start the loop for the next 5 lines and so on. Please help to provide the way.

Comment: Altered script to do what you ask

Comment: Many Thanks Ram ! That command worked fine for me, but i got the below error, might be this is because of awk or something in regular expression matching.                                                 It created the file upto file11974.                               bash-3.00$ awk 'BEGIN{fnum=1;}($1=="dn:"){flag=1; x=""}(flag==1){x=x "\n" $0}($1=="-"){flag=0; fn="file" fnum; print x > fn; fnum++;}' file_name
awk: 0602-575 Cannot find or open file file1996.
 The input line number is 11975. The file is file_name.
 The source line number is 1.
bash-3.00$

Comment: sorry it created the file upto : file1995.

Comment: Thats because you are running out of file descriptors. I've edited the solution to close each file after it is written into. Its good to be aware of the various resource limits imposed upon you by any system. For instance, you are typically allowed to have only a limited number of files open at the same time. The command "ulimit -a" tells you the limits on various resources. I predict that if you try that command, you will find the number of open files to be limited a little higher than 1995.

Comment: Thanks Ram a ton ! Worked Fine. Open Files is 2000 as per the below command.                                                        bash-3.00$ ulimit -a
core file size        (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size         (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size             (blocks, -f) unlimited
max memory size       (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                    (-n) 2000
pipe size          (512 bytes, -p) 64
stack size            (kbytes, -s) hard
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes            (-u) 16384
virtual memory        (kbytes, -v) unlimited
bash-3.00$